# Как из unknown грамотно вызывать toString?

Tags: typescript

Хочу написать функцию которая будет возвращать `string` из неизвестного значения

Так как я не могу знать, что туда положили изначально, но хочу по `феншую` описать тип, я не использую `any`, а использую `unknown`

Но вопрос, как грамотно из него можно вызвать метод `toString`?

Что бы `typescript` не ругался

[image: Ошибка при вызове метода из unknown]

Comment: а вы уверены, что у value всегда будет метод `toString`?

Comment: для этого можно прописать дополнительную проверку `value?.toString?.()`,

но это к сожалению не то, на что ругается `typescript `

@xydope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typescript не позволяет вам использовать переменную неизвестного типа, если вы либо не приведете переменную к известному типу, либо не сузите ее тип.

```
export const intoString = (value: unknown) => (value as any)?.toString?.() ?? '';
```

Comment: Поделитесь пожалуйста источником

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type "unknown isn’t assignable to anything but itself and any without a type assertion or a control flow based narrowing"

Comment: а если number передать, то пустая строка вернется )

Comment: @xydope, по идее не имеет значения, компилятор должен проглотить все кроме undefined (я имею ввиду этап компиляции, а не выполнения)

Comment: тогда мне кажется правильно будет написать `export const intoString = (value: any) => value?.toString?.() ?? ''`, в таком виде читаемость не страдает и не надо танцевать с бубном `as`

Comment: @UserTest013 еще как имеет, в текущем виде ваше решение работает неправильно.

Comment: @UserTest013 я согласен с **xydope** , первая строчка не подходит для решения моей задачи

Comment: @xydope, почему не правильно? 10?.toString() возвращает "10"

Comment: @UserTest013 в первой строчке написано если не объект вернуть пустую строку

Comment: @UserTest013 так вы всю функцию вызывайте `intoString1(10)`

Comment: Понял, согласен. Тогда только (value as any) проходит

Comment: @xydope я предполагаю, что первая строчка была пояснением к _либо не сузите ее тип_

Просто неудачно вышло)

Comment: @UserTest013 предлагаю вам поправить ответ, для людей из будущего)

Comment: @UserTest013 везде работает, т.к. в этом выражении нет смысла

Comment: @UserTest013 Еще 1 момент, в вашем варианте вы не можете гарантировать, что toString будет возвращать тип `string`, [пример](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmKIDKUBOCDmMC8MAUAbgIYA2ArgKYBcM5YA1mCAO5gCU10GY2OAfARIVKMYhDFgAnuwD8AOiSoemBfnYwAPppgByXQG4AsAChTp0JFgQQAW1F4A3qZiuYYYvdoAiYOWh23gA0Lm7CVLQAjABMAMwhJm4wSuhY6s6JSW5olFDkaGAwGVkl7p40egAmlJQADgDC-ki2uqElAL5tMO1Jpp1mJpbQyQAeULTcWLjwiCipvPg29uwW4DaklPKkIJj4UFK1lCAAZqNQ7EA).

Comment: не надо `as any`, достаточно `as object`

Comment: Упадёт, если `toString` будет, но не функцией.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких вещей используют не `unknown`, а [дженерики](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Неплохой практикой будет, если вам нужно писать ф-цию, решения которой для вас затруднительно, то начинайте с описания типа функции.

В целом, можно вообще от подобной идеи отказаться и просто использовать `String('аргумент')`

```js
type SomeToStringFn = <T>(value: T)=>string //тип функции, что-то принимает, возвращает строку.

const convertToString:SomeToStringFn = (value) => String(value) //сама функция.
```

Comment: Ваш вариант действительно хорошо, про `дженерики` я думал, но там была проблема с методом `toString`

Решение через `String` действительно хорошее, но под мою задачу я бы переписал вот так

`export const intoString = <T>(value: T) => (value ? String(value) : '')`

Comment: Предыдущий ответ оставил с галочкой, так как человек объяснил почему именно с `unknown` невозможно решить и поделился источником, но ваш ответ в плане реализации сильно лучше 

Comment: @user447630 1. это приведет к неправильному поведение, т.к. при любом Boolean отрицательном значении, вы будете получать пустую строку. Попробуйте в вашем варианте вызвать `intoString(0)` или `intoString(false)`

Comment: У меня такой кейс, https://ibb.co/LhSwdd8 . Но вы подсказали отличный кейс с `true` 

Answer (score 1):

Сделать можно по-разному, но и результат будет разный: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAjACgB4C5HgNZhwDuYAlIgN4BQiiATgKZQh1IBEbiA1IhlQL5UqoSLATIATJhz5CJctVqNmrRAGUodGGADmmUgKEjo8JMADM03GALEylGvSYskUAJ4AHBnGCJMiAEMAZ0CwN1IAfgA6KDgNLV1EAF4UxDZjMTBOADJsvwxAkICwyJi4zW09cgAfarS2Q2FwE3FgABYrWTsFR2UXRAB5ACMAKwZoKI86OFj3LzL4yqiIAIAbVf0AbkaM02QAVk6bOXtFJxUkf2DQ8IWK3TQDQSoIBCCoRBWghhCkh1pwAATBjAbQMQEAGkcYBA6xwMPWUNoQTcAFshnBVjg1GiMRtSEi0hREAA3NYgBgDYCPSjnfoADnpiH4zLYOGJZNWFKpNOJfVUjOZzMJbBpSQAfJR+Gy-OQJVKRcTYosHgo6aoAJwaoXS9mIZX3Kq0-lILU6kXDMYTCCMAJQBhoBGrUgyy3jKDLW32x2w51Q56vMDvJxBPUAbTwDDcOHeCR0AF1w5Ho4hY5VE9ZbCQdckpUY4HQ-IHg2GwAFUQwIYg4KN49XfG6JgwwBUfmgvj9SD1aMWPhAWEmozHDRmutmWX9GEFS+WGHW-hRBLRHMAC0W3h8w8AyxWq8A6z5BqN3VFm62gmhiag9xI9+Y921mV3-rR9XQ3C-X58WFud3Pc9SNYjAYX4sisUAQAAFn4DB0HQ3Zft+dC-rO86ILBdCOLQS7Mo0xaYgwMQBEMqwOlOpBAA)

```
function f1(x: unknown) {
  return "" + x
}

function f2(x: unknown) {
  return String(x)
}

function f3(x: unknown) {
  return `${x}`
}

function f4(x: unknown) {
  return typeof (x as any)?.toString === "function" && (x as any)?.toString() || ""
}

function f5(x: unknown) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x);
}

function f6(x: unknown) {
  return (x as any).toString()
}

function f7(x: unknown) {
  return (x as any)?.toString()
}

const cases = {
  undefined,
  null: null,
  symbol: Symbol(),
  "{ valueOf() { return 88 } }": { valueOf() { return 88 } },
  "() => {}": () => {},
  "{ toString() { return 99 } }": { toString() { return 99 } },
  "Object.create(null)": Object.create(null),
}

const res: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: unknown } } = {}

for (const [name, obj] of Object.entries(cases)) {
  const cur: { [key: string]: unknown } = res[name] = {}
  
  for (const f of [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7]) {
    try {
      cur[f as any] = f(obj)
    } catch (err) {
      cur[f as any] = err
    }
  }
}

console.table(res)
```

А вот получившаяся таблица:

[image: скриншот таблицы]

Comment: Спасибо за интересный пример